# Search all pcap files in a folder and sub-folders for a certain condition

Tags: pcap

I have a folder (containing many sub-folders) full of pcap files and I'd like to get all pcap files containing packets that match a certain condition, for example "have source IP 1.1.1.1". Do you know any tool that does that kind of search?

I need this both for Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PcapSearch](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/PcapSearch) does exactly what you need. It's part of the [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus) library and it's cross-platform so it'd work on Windows and Linux

In your case use it as follows (Linux case):

```
./PcapSearch -d /your/folder/ -s "ip src 1.1.1.1"
```

you can also use the -r switch to write results to a file, it'll also print the match packets to that report

**EDIT:** if you don't want or can't compile this utility, please take a look at PcapPlusPlus [recent release](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/releases/tag/v16.09), it contains binaries for quite a lot of platforms such as Windows, Ubuntu (12.04/14.04) and Mac OS X (Mavericks/Yosemite/El Capitan)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! it's exactly the tool I was looking for